# Javascript - How to check if argument in function at specific 'index' is missing?

Tags: javascript, arguments

I want to return different statements based on whether or not an argument is undefined. The problem is that if lets say the 2nd parameter is missing, the 3rd argument 'becomes' the second argument so that no matter WHICH argument is missing, im hitting only the last else if statement (which should apply only when the last argument is missing). I have researched but can't find the solution. I tried to use

```
var array=Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
```

And then check for array[0], array[1] and array[2] but that also doesn't work as I ALWAYS get 'c doesnt exist'
Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

```
function testing(a, b, c) {
    if (a === undefined) {
        return 'a doesnt exist'
    } else if (b === undefined) {
        return 'b doesnt exist'
    } else if (c === undefined) {
        return 'c doesnt exist'
    }
}

testing(3, 'name')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the caller only calls your function with two arguments, you have no idea whether it's the second or third parameter that's missing unless you can infer it from the types you're expecting.  For instance, if you expect `b` to be a number and `c` to be a function, then:

```
if (typeof b === "function") {
    // `b` was omitted (effectively)
    c = b;
    b = undefined;
}
```

But if you're expecting the same type of argument for `b` and `c`, or you're allowing any type for them, then there's no way for you to know whether the caller supplying only two arguments means to supply `a` and `b` or `a` and `c`.

In that case, you'd have to document the function to say that if you want to (effectively) leave off `b`, you need to provide `undefined` for it: `testing(1, undefined, 3);` (And doing that plays nicely with ES2015's default arguments, whereas leaving it out entirely does not.)

Another way to accept complex combinations of arguments it to accept an object rather than discrete params:

```js
function testing(options) {
  console.log("a:", options.a);
  console.log("b:", options.b);
  console.log("c:", options.c);
}

// Usage
testing({a: 1, c: 3});
```

And if you did that, and if you can use ES2015 (aka "ES6") features (e.g., you're targeting only cutting-edge browsers, or you're transpiling), you could use *argument destructuring* to get them automatically mapped to parameters for you:

```js
function testing({a, b, c}) {
  console.log("a:", a);
  console.log("b:", b);
  console.log("c:", c);
}

// Usage
testing({a: 1, c: 3});
```

You can even combine that with default parameter values:

```js
function testing({a = 1, b = 2, c = 3}) {
  console.log("a:", a);
  console.log("b:", b);
  console.log("c:", c);
}

// Usage
testing({a: 1, c: 3});
```

Answer (score 0):

Or just make sure you invoke your function with all three arguments, eg:

```
testing(3, undefined, 'name');
```